# + selector not applying when intermediary dom element appended

Tags: css, html, sass

Currently I have a tweaked radio button coded :

```
<label>
    <input type="radio" ... />
    <span>...</span>
</label>
```

And some CSS applying to the first element following the input once checked like :

```
input:checked + span {
    ...
  }
```

It works perfectly well: when the label is clicked, the input gets in checked state and the CSS does apply to the span element (change of text color ..)

**Though now I add an image just before the span :**

```
<label>
    <input type="radio" ... />
    <img ... />
    <span>...</span>
</label>
```

with similar CSS added on top of previous :

```
input:checked + img {
    ...
  }
```

**Now what happens is** : the image is applied the right CSS when the image  is clicked. Though the span is no longer changed now. I don't understand what gets in the way. `+` is still relevant as in both cases `span` and `img` are the direct following elements (of their type)

Comment: great thanks. Never heard of `~` but it does fix. I thought `+` was applying to the first element of its kind, not an adjacent element. Good to know.

Answer (score 2):

What gets in the way is that the "+" selector means "select the *x* that's **immediately** after the *y*". Once you get the img in the middle, the span is no longer immediately after the input.

You might want to use the `~` general sibling combinator instead of the `+` adjacent sibling combinator.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_selectors

Answer (score 1):

You should use:

```
input:checked ~ span {
    ...
}
```

That's how you can reach the span element